# What means "_" symbol in Kotlin?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, underscores

I tried to find information what it means but I didn't. Trying to understand what it does in this code:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_` Used for

- substitutes an unused parameter in a lambda expression
- substitutes an unused parameter in a destructuring declaration

For more information check this [Keywords and Operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#keywords-and-operators)

Comment: Why some people use "buttonView" instead of "_"? Is there any difference?

Comment: if you want use `buttonView` parameter inside `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` then you can use parameter as  `buttonView` and if you don't want to use  `buttonView` parameter inside `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`  then simply use `_`

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, if you use _, you are disallowed from using it at all. The reason for the feature is that it’s a waste of time to have to come up with a variable name if you aren’t going to use it anyway.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you, for clarity, can you give me simple example where I can use this variable? I'm begginer. I thought that variable is "checkbox".

Comment: The first variable is the check box. You wouldn't need it unless using a shared OnCheckedChangeListener among several CompoundButtons (the superclass of CheckBox). Then you could pass the same instance to several different CompoundButtons, and distinguish which one got changed by checking the first variable. IMO that is a more convoluted design. In Java it can lead to more compact code by avoiding all the anonymous classes. In Kotlin it doesn't lead to more compact code.

Comment: The reason you don't need the first variable is that you already have a reference to your check box that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

when user does't need a parameter in lembda expression then we can use "_"

```
 setOnTouchListener { _, p1 ->
            if (p1.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                hideKeyboard()
                true
            } else
                false
        }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32787702)

Comment: when user does't need a parameter in lembda expression then we can use "_" .

Comment: you should edit your answer and add this information to it